# $firebaseObject.$save() overwrites the whole node

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I have a plunker where I have a simple update-Method to update a recorcd. But when I add or update a property to the record, the whole record will be overwritten.

**The Data**

```
{
  "org1" : {
    "description" : "too lazy",
    "name" : "Apple",
    "website" : "http://www.apple.com"
  },
  "org2" : {
    "name" : "Google",
    "test1" : "test123",
    "website" : "http://www.google.com"
  }
}
```

**update()**

```
this.update = function() {
  //var obj = new Organization('org2');
  var obj = $firebaseObject(new Firebase('https://thefactorymess.firebaseio-demo.com/organizations/org2'));
  obj.test1 = 'test123';
  obj.$save().then(function() {
    console.log('org new', obj);
  });
};
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0S86fU2WBvc9l97unbjd?p=preview).

Can someone explain me this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AngularFire `$save()` method indeed overwrites the current data at that location. It is implemented by calling the `set()` method of Firebase's JavaScript SDK, which does precisely that.

Since you're calling `$save()` immediately after creating the reference, the data hasn't been loaded from the Firebase servers yet. So you're creating an object with a single properties `test1`. When you then `$save()` that object to the server, you end up with an object with a single property there too.

If you only want to update some properties, you can call `update()`.

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://thefactorymess.firebaseio-demo.com/organizations/org2');

ref.update({ test1: 'test123' });
```

This doesn't use AngularFire. But since AngularFire is built on top of the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK, they interoperate without problems.

Alternatively you could use AngularFire's `$loaded()` promise to wait for the object to have loaded completely. But that would lead to both a lot more code and pulling down data.

My rule of thumb is:

> Only use AngularFire for binding things to the `$scope`. For everything else, use the Firebase JavaScript SDK.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. Does your rule of thumb also include adding, updating and deleting records with AngularFire? And you further explain me it?

Comment: If you want to update something that is bound to the $scope already, by all means use `$save()`. But it is a waste of good code to first create a `$firebaseObject()` only to then call `$save()` on it. Just read the guide for Firebase's JavaScript SDK and use that for things that are not immediately binding to the UI: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/